# Re-render ItemView throw Controller

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have one ItemView, then I send throw .trigger() to another controller

Message View

```
Bintime.module("Message.Input", function(Input, Bintime, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Input.Contacts = Marionette.ItemView.extend ({
        template: "#new",
        events: {
            "change input#message-input": "sendInput"
        },
        sendInput: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var message = this.$("input#message-input").val();
            this.model.get("messages").push({
                to: "1",
                message: message
            });
            this.render();
            this.trigger("chat:contacts", this.model);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Message Controller

```
Bintime.module("Message.Input", function(Input, Bintime, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Input.Controller = {
        messageField: function(model){
            var contacts = new Input.Contacts({
                model: model
            });

            contacts.on("childview:chat:contacts", function(childView, model) {
                Bintime.Contacts.Messages.Controller.chatMessages(model);
            });

            Bintime.regions.input.show(contacts);
        }
    }
});
```

---

And here is chat controller

```
Bintime.module("Contacts.Messages", function(Messages, Bintime, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    Messages.Controller = {
        chatMessages: function(model){
            var contacts = new Messages.Contact({
                model: model
            });

            Marionette.Renderer.render("#message", model);

            Bintime.regions.messages.show(contacts);
        }
    }
});
```

Is it everything true, and should working with `Marionette.Renderer.render("#message", model);`

Or I should use another method to work with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you're doing with the renderer, but one issue is that your `ItemView` is not going to prefix its events with `"childview:"`  so that binding should look more like `contacts.on("chat:contacts"`

Also instead of Bintime.Contacts.Messages.Controller.chatMessages(model); you might throw a Wreqr/Radio event that the other module can listen to.. but I think the biggest issue here is that "childview:chat:contacts" isn't an event that is getting thrown.